# A CSS property which have been used for animation can't be used for hover in chrome

Tags: html, css, css-animations

If I use a CSS property for css animation, and if I use that property for a hovering effect as well, in google chrome, the hovering won't work.

Here's the animation code :

```
@keyframes fadeInUpBig {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(2000px);
    transform: translateY(2000px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.fadeInUpBig {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUpBig;
  animation-name: fadeInUpBig;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Here's the hover code :

```
.sImg:hover{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    @include scale(1.2);
}
```

A working demo (The 5 round images at the bottom should scale on hover.) : http://secret-temple-3539.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Demo please in JS fiddle

Comment: @Paulie_D Ah sorry... here's a working demo : http://secret-temple-3539.herokuapp.com/ The 5 round images at the bottom should scale on hover.

Comment: OK...now what am I looking for...what element?

Comment: @Paulie_D At the end, there are 5 big circles. Those circles should scale when hovered. But they are not doing that. In firefox this works. But in Chrome (under webkit) it won't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `transform` to the container `div` instead of the `img` tag like shown below and it should work according to your expectation.

```
.sImgCont:hover {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); /* for older versions, add other browser prefixes as you need */
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Alternately, you can make the `a` as a `block` (using `display: block`) and add the `transform` to it. (Least preferred option)

Add the `transition` also to either the `div` or the `a` to make the transformation smoother.

I don't think Chrome (webkit) supports scaling of non-block elements (EDIT: As mentioned [here](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/solved-webkit-transform-not-working/)).

**Edit 2:** Should have mentioned that the above answer is one possible solution to the problem you had mentioned in the comments.

For your original question, the problem seems to be with the `-webkit-animation-fill-mode` property. The value `both` seems to be actually causing the problem when both the `animated` and `fadeInUpBig` classes are used together. As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7qRa/1/) when the value is changed to `backwards` it works fine. ( `forwards` also doesn't work)

**Edit 3:** This is another simpler [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nYCHg/1/) that may help you understand. In this, you would see that I have applied two transformations (one through initial animation and one on hover) and you would find that the ones with fill mode as forwards/both do not perform the transformation on hover while the one with backwards does.

The only explanation that I have is because both `forwards` and `both` makes the `div` hold its final state which is an already transformed one and hence another one on top of it is not being taken. However the `backwards` mode restores the div back to its original position before/without the transformation (which was 0px) and is hence able to accept the transformation that is specified on hover.

Possible reason is that, in CSS, for an element only one transformation property can be specified/present at the same time (try giving two different `-webkit-transform` lines within the same class and see that only one will take effect) and hence when you try to apply a new transformation to an element which is already holding a transformed state, it is not working.

**Note:** This is not a definitive answer, but I am leaving it here because the analysis might help somebody in future.

Comment: Thanks. I gave the animated class to the div and it worked perfectly! :-)